# Global data in Application Controller? -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have several elements that are needed in each view and trying to set them in the application controller (which doesn't work)...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  @top_categories = Category.top.limit(10)

end
```

**How could I make that global data available in all views?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could wrap that in  a function and specify as a helper for example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base    
    helper_method :top_categories

    def top_categories
        Category.top.limit(10)
    end
end
```

This will be available in all views and controllers

Comment: So in my code I would traverse it normally? i.e. `top_categories.each do ...` ?

Comment: Yes, that will return the array of Category s you were looking for.